# Stdout for a subprocess when launching with --screen

Tags: roslaunch, rosrun

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the following three lines buried within a node (let's call it `network_scanner.py`):

```
    cmd = ["sudo", "iwlist", "wlan0", "scan"]
    proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    iwlist_output = proc.communicate()[0].decode('utf-8')
```

If I call my launch file (`roslaunch network_scanner network_scanner.launch --screen`), `iwlist_output` is completely empty.

If I run the node directly (`rosrun network_scanner network_scanner.py`), I get expected output in `iwlist_output`.

I'm assuming the problem is that `proc` is unable to provide output to `stdout` for some reason when I `roslaunch` my node. Shouldn't `--screen` fix that?

Edit: Question assumed that there was an issue with `stdout`, but that wasn't the issue. The problem was that `cmd` wasn't being properly called because of permissions. [This post](http://answers.ros.org/question/165246/launch-node-with-root-permissions/) provides a solution.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/253182/stdout-for-a-subprocess-when-launching-with---screen/) by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2017-01-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-28**:
`--screen` redirects the output of your node; it shouldn't affect things that your node is running within subprocess.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-01-28**:
I've seen some of the wifi scanning commands return different results on consecutive runs, so you may want to try multiple runs to confirm that this isn't just random behavior

**Comment by [spmaniato](https://answers.ros.org/users/20159/spmaniato/) on 2017-01-28**:
I haven't encountered this particular issue, but I've successfully used `commands.getstatusoutput(my_cmd_string)` from the `commands` module within a ROS node without any problems. However, "Using the `subprocess` module is preferable to using the `commands` module."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually, turns out it's a problem with `sudo` rather than with `stdout`: I wasn't getting prompted to enter my password when using `roslaunch`, but I was with `rosrun` -- seems like the command might not have been run at all.

---

Originally posted by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) with karma: 539 on 2017-01-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2017-01-28**:
@ahendrix Your solution in [this post](http://answers.ros.org/question/165246/launch-node-with-root-permis) seems like the best way forward. Thanks!

Edit: Fixed link